# Laravel 5.5 - Notification channels different queue names?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-queue, laravel-notification

In an event listener, I send a notification to a dog owner like this:

```
$event->dogowner->notify(new DogWasWalkedNotification);
```

The issue is since there are **two** channels `database`/`mail` set in the Notification below, they **both** get added as queued jobs on the 'notifications' queue, set in the constructor. Instead, I want to add the mail channel below to an `emails` queue instead of the default one set in the constructor of 'notifications'.

Any idea how to have the following notification only add the mail channel `MailMessage` to an `emails` queue **without** adding the `database` channel to a queue at all? (even if that means removing the constructor `onQueue`)

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\Events\DogWasWalked;

class DogWasWalkedNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $event;

    public function __construct(DogWasWalked $event) {
        $this->event = $event;

        // This is what creates 2 queued jobs (one per channel)
        $this->onQueue('notifications');
    }

    public function via($notifiable) {
        return ['database', 'mail'];
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable) {
        return [
            'activity' => 'Dog was walked!',
            'walkername' => $this->event->walkername
        ];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable) {
      // How to set the queue name for
      // this channel to 'emails'
      return (new MailMessage)
             ->line('Dog was walked!');

    }
}
```

Comment: `database` and `mail` are channels this notification should send to, and they respects to the queue you specified so I don't think it can be done. Did you mean you want to add this notification to database without queue, but queue the mails? I suggest split the notification up if that's the case.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I meant. What do you mean by split them up?

Comment: One notification for mail, another for database, that's what I can think of, since there is no way to split them up via one notification

Comment: Yeah, but I was really trying to keep all channels in notification with different queues as needed. So db no queue, but toMail `emails` queue, and as another example of what I am trying to achieve toSlack 'slack' queue. I have a feeling there must be a way to assign different channels to different queues under one notification...

Comment: Hmm, if that's the case, you might want to extend NotificationSender and create one for your own usage. [Check the core codes here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f4eb7056751dd27ab7e8d57a4dd0473315b8e357/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php#L151-L162), it uses just one queue for all channels, which make sense for almost all common cases.